# My project does not want to finalize syncing

Tags: java, android, macos, gradle

I am a beginner in java. I want  to load a source code on my android studio to later edit, but I keep getting the below message and the project syncing is not stopping too.

> Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: GradleProject.getProjectDirectory().
>               The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
>               To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>               Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model. (34 s 135 ms)

Answer (score 0):

import your project to android studio using ==>> File-> new -> Import Project and In your build.gradle change the Android tools build version to the recent gradle version for example `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'` , also 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file must be according to your gradle, I mean `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`